# Graphic issue 'only' in UEFI mode on Kubuntu 15.x on i5 6600k Skylake

Tags: kubuntu, uefi

I recently a built a new system with 
**Intel i5 6600k Skylake CPU**  
 **ASUS Z170 MoBo**. 
Its an **UEFI + GPT** system with **Windows 10**.

When I booted LiveUSB in BIOS mode it booted but shutdown monitor when reaching KDE splash screen. Then I booted with nomodeset and it booted fine with correct resolution.
I liked it so decided to install it. So I booted in *UEFI mode* with ***nomodeset*** but this time I got low resolution of **1024x768**. I anyways went on to install it and update it but no difference.

System does not even boot with **i915.preliminary_hw_support=1**. Blank screen. 
 **lspci -ks 0:02** shows **Onboard IGD** and no kernel module.

Here's my `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
bluetooth             507904  5 bnep
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   499712  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
joydev                 20480  0
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
soundcore              16384  1 snd
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
shpchp                 36864  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
mac_hid                16384  0
industrialio           57344  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
i915                 1105920  0
e1000e                233472  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
drm                   356352  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  36864  2 i915,asus_wmi
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
```

Here's my `lsmod | grep -i i915`

```
i915                 1105920  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
drm                   356352  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
video                  36864  2 i915,asus_wmi
```

I tried **blacklisting asus_wmi** but it keeps loading.

Please help me get my Graphic Card (**Intel HD 530**) up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Kernel 4.3 from [Ubuntu Mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/)

and my graphic issue is resolved.